# How does one get an order confirmation email to fire immediately in Commerce 3?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce3

Curious if there is a way to fire order confirmation emails immediately? Basically how this was handled in Commerce 2.

There are cases, and I'm dealing with one currently, where there is no command line access to the hosting or the possibility of setting up cron jobs and the likes to trigger the queue on an interval...

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options here.

**Number 1**

If you have the config setting `runQueueAutomatically` set to `false` you could call the controller action `queue/run` via ajax from your success page. This would trigger the queue to run.

**Number 2**

You can use the `EVENT_AFTER_COMPLETE_ORDER` event to run some custom code, in a module or plugin. In that code you can include `Craft::$app->getQueue()->run()` this will also trigger the queue to run. e.g.

```php
Event::on(Order::class, Order::EVENT_AFTER_COMPLETE_ORDER, function(Event $e) {
    Craft::$app->getQueue()->run();
});
```

Comment: I'm not extremely adept with the yii/php side of things in Craft, I'm assuming this would need to be wrapped into a module's functionality.

Comment: ... Meaning inside an init() function or something like that.

Comment: Yea @Anders that is right 

Comment: Figured it out, thanks!

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Answer (score 2):

I like this solution:

```
{# run queue #}
{% do craft.app.queue.handleResponse %}
{{ craft.app.response.content|raw }}
```

Detailed in [this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35606/craft-commerce-not-sending-e-mails-immediately).

Answer (score 1):

Per request; I basically just dropped the code into the example module that comes with craft. I have some other modules and didn't want to clutter things. Here's the full code of the module;

```
<?php
namespace modules;

use Craft;
use craft\commerce\elements\Order;
use yii\base\Event;

/**
 * Custom module class.
 *
 * This class will be available throughout the system via:
 * `Craft::$app->getModule('my-module')`.
 *
 * You can change its module ID ("my-module") to something else from
 * config/app.php.
 *
 * If you want the module to get loaded on every request, uncomment this line
 * in config/app.php:
 *
 *     'bootstrap' => ['my-module']
 *
 * Learn more about Yii module development in Yii's documentation:
 * http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html
 */
class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    /**
     * Initializes the module.
     */
    public function init()
    {
        // Set a @modules alias pointed to the modules/ directory
        Craft::setAlias('@modules', __DIR__);

        // Set the controllerNamespace based on whether this is a console or web request
        if (Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsConsoleRequest()) {
            $this->controllerNamespace = 'modules\\console\\controllers';
        } else {
            $this->controllerNamespace = 'modules\\controllers';
        }

        parent::init();

        // Custom initialization code goes here...
        Event::on(Order::class, Order::EVENT_AFTER_COMPLETE_ORDER, function(Event $e) {
            Craft::$app->getQueue()->run();
        });
    }
}
```